# Navision SOAP read request returns 'FlowField' error

Tags: php, soap, navision

I'm trying to get all the records out of a certain Navision (MS Dynamic Nav) service, like so:

```
$item->ReadMultiple(['filter' => [], 'setSize' => 100]);
```

But this gives me a strange error:

```
[SoapFault]                                                   
The Date Filter field in the Item table must be a FlowField.
```

I'm not even filtering on the "Date_Filter" field. Is this a problem in the navision database itself?

This is the definition of the 'Date Filter' field in the WS_Item complex type:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Date_Filter" type="xsd:date"/>
```

Is there anything I can do on my end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is on Nav side. Either someone is trying to `calcfields("Date filter");` or it is just prohibited to populate flow filters in a web services.

Comment: It was on their end, indeed. The Navision administrator removed all the flow fields from the webservice and now it's running smoothly.